# Windows disappeared from grub menu after deleting Ubuntu partition

Tags: grub2, boot-failure

I was having problem with booting Ubuntu. Then I used Easeus partition manager to delete the partition that has Ubuntu. Maybe I have done it wrong. Because now I have also lost Windows. Luckily I came to know of a tool called boot repair from this forum. I used and here is the result from it [Paste bin boot info summary](http://pastebin.com/QTxRPRwy). Can someone please decipher what this says and possibly help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have windows recovery disk? If yes, you can repair boot record from Windows recovery disk.

Use `fixmbr` command.

Comment: I don't have windows recovery disk. If that is the ONLY solution I can make one by downloading from the internet.[And also how can I make a "recovery" disk for windows if I have just the windows 7 installation iso] I have very slow internet connection. So I hope that is not the only solution

Comment: From your BootInfo script we can see that the Windows boot sector was overwritten. No way to fix other than with a Windows recovery. This can also be done from an installation CD (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-are-the-system-recovery-options-in-Windows-7). Of course after that you will not be able to boot Ubuntu again until you reinstall Grub.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution with Win PE

If you have a Win PE system , install it onto your usb key or burn a CD.

Downlaod `http://www.sysint.no/nedlasting/mbrfix.htm` and try the command.

I've done this multiple times , it's easy to fix.

### Solution with grub-0.9*

Use grub to load your windows , e.g

```
grub> rootnoverify (hdA,B)
grub> makeactive
grub> chainloader +1
grub> boot
```

It may fail , but worth a try. (At least for Windows XP I tried last time)

Answer (score 0):

You need either Windows disk or (Ubuntu) Linux live CD/USB. Do everything possible to boot into a live desktop/system.

For Windows, in command prompt run `fixmbr`.

For Ubuntu or other Linux live-system,

**Method 1: Install syslinux.**

```
sudo apt-get install syslinux
```

Then, use following commands write mbr (Use `sudo fdisk -l` to find out your device name):

```
sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda
```

**Method 2: Install mbr**

```
sudo apt-get install mbr
```

Then, write mbr by:

```
sudo install-mbr -i n -p D -t 0 /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you don't have a windows disc, try reinstalling grub from a ubuntu live cd:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows