# Can't Load Windows 8 after removing Ubuntu Dual Boot

Tags: boot, grub2

I deleted Ubuntu and I can't load in windows 8 I get grub rescue. I have the installation disc for windows 8 and don't want to reinstall Ubuntu. I had this b4 but can't remember how I did it. Ubuntu is already gone and windows is downloaded I just want to be able to get on windows because grub rescue is preventing me.

Answer (score 1):

Boot from the windows DVD into the repair mode and enter the command `fixmbr`.

More [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125075/windows-disappeared-from-grub-menu-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on).